# How to Import Elixir Dependencies Into Current File/Module

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm trying to use the Hex packaged CSV.

I'm added the dependency to mix.exs like so:

```
  def application do
    [applications: [:logger, :csv]]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:csv, "~> 1.4.2"}
    ]
```

Then, I run `mix deps.get` & `mix deps.compile` in terminal.

The dependency folder shows up in deps folder.

Everything seems to be okay until I try to use the dependency.  I'm getting this error:

> "module CSV is not loaded and could not be found"

I've tried a simply use without importing like so:

```
File.stream!("data.csv") |> CSV.decode
```

I've tried importing like so:

```
import(CSV)
File.stream!("data.csv") |> CSV.decode
```

I've tried prefixing the deps directory:

```
import(deps.CSV)
File.stream!("data.csv") |> CSV.decode
```

And the full path to the deps subdirectory:

```
import(deps.csv.lib.csv.CSV)
File.stream!("data.csv") |> CSV.decode
```

No matter what it doesn't seem to find the dependency module.

What am I missing?

Comment: [project_name]/lib/[project_name]/scratch_pads/scratch_pad_2.ex

Comment: Probably a bug in the Atom plugin then. Which one are you using which lets you execute a file? In the meantime, you can run the code from the shell using `mix run lib/[project_name]/scratch_pads/scratch_pad_2‌​.ex`.

Comment: You don't need to import the CSV module unless you want to use its functions without having to fully qualify them. The easiest way to test what is available to you is to run `iex -S mix` which will start your application and open an `iex` shell where you can call Modules directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your IDE is misconfigured. Here is an command line example of how to get up and running.

```sh
mix new csv_tester
cd csv_tester
# edit mix.exs to add {:csv, "~> 1.4"} to your deps, like you have above
mix deps.get
iex -S mix
```

```
iex(1)> [["name", "age"], ["Bob Saget", 64]] |> CSV.encode() |> Enum.join("")
"name,age\r\nBob Saget,64\r\n"
```

Modules are globally accessible, so you do not need to use the `import` statement unless you only want a specific function in a given module, or you do not want to have to fully qualify the function call with the Module name. See [import](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2) docs.

Anything that you can execute in `iex` you should be able to call from any other Module in your project

If you still need help debugging, you can run this in iex to list all modules that should be available at runtime and then filter for anything containing CSV in the module name:

```
iex(1)> :code.get_path() |> 
  Enum.map(&to_charlist/1) |> 
  Enum.map(&:erl_prim_loader.list_dir/1) |> 
  Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1)) |> 
  Enum.concat() |> 
  Enum.map(&to_string/1) |> 
  Enum.filter(fn module -> module =~ "CSV" end)
```

Which should output something like this

```
["Elixir.CSV.Encode.beam", "Elixir.CSV.Encoder.beam", "Elixir.CSV.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Lexer.EncodingError.beam", "Elixir.CSV.LineAggregator.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Parser.beam", "Elixir.CSV.Lexer.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Encode.BitString.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.LineAggregator.CorruptStreamError.beam", "Elixir.CSV.Decoder.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Decoder.RowLengthError.beam", "Elixir.CSV.Encode.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Parser.SyntaxError.beam", "Elixir.CSV.Encode.Any.beam",
 "Elixir.CSV.Defaults.beam"]
```

Comment: Given that `:code.get_path()` returns a list of charlists, not a list of strings, `|> Enum.map(&to_charlist/1)` is not needed and can be ommited. More generally, "when interfacing with Erlang, in particular when using older libraries" the arguments and return values tend to be charlists, not UTF-8 binaries (aka strings in Elixir).